# How to stick together objects for animation? (Chainmail cape)

Tags: modeling, animation, unity, cloth-simulation, parent

i am creating archer warrior asset for a game, and need to somehow stick top and bottom part of "chainmail" cape to head and maybe to body, so it holds and bends correctly while animating.
[image]

[image]

I could make a top of the hat too, and not try to stick it to head, but i want to know how to do it this way.

Also i want this to bend realistically, like chainmail / cloth would do.
Is is possible to stick it to the head, and how?
And what is the best approach in making this work?

I use blender and unity.

Thanks

Comment: Typical workflow is to make the helmet/chainmail part of the character and then add deform bones along the chainmail part so that you can animate it.  It seems to be the only way to get realistic movement of the chainmail in blender.

Comment: I thought so. I ended up doing it kinda like that. I was thinking about some sort of cloth simulation in unity, but that seems to be really overkill for this. 
I still don't know tho, if it is possible to somehow align those top vertices to the head. Merging them would definitelly be bad workflow. No? If it is even possible to merge a plane with closed mesh.